# AWS Instance Launch Failed - Instance reachability check failed

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have scenario where AMI created from certain instances do not work. I get the error "Instance reachability check failed". I have analysed more and found that AMI crated from instance having multiple private IP (and so DHCP is disabled for internet traffic and it goes through primary private IP) do not work. Instance which do not have more than one private IP (and so DHCP enabled) works fine. Kindly advise if any work around/solution for this.